# What should be checked in junit for a method that simply calls super.method()?

Tags: java, inheritance, junit, mockito, assert

I have a *junit method* that only calls `super.method()`. 
What should be asserted in the junit for this method.

```
public String foo()
{
   return super.foo();
}
```

Is asserting that the `super.foo()` is getting called enough.

Or, I should compare the values as well.

Comment: What are you testing?

Comment: I am writing a Junit. My intention is to test the behavior AND the code as well ensuring it has 100% coverage, but I am open to suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

This is an interesting question and I doubt can be answered without more context and understanding of the importance of this code.

If you want to favor isolated tests then I would say there is little to test here. Instead, I would ensure that `super.foo()` was well tested in the test class for the superclass. The advantage of this approach means that if the superclass' behavior changes the unit tests only need updating in one place.

However, if there is a strong business reason for this behavior then it could make sense to test that the implementation here as well. With careful reuse of code in the unit tests, it would minimize the maintenance headache moving forward.

Essentially the choice of what and how to test this method comes down to a balance between completeness of coverage and cost of ongoing maintenance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't test the *implementation*: test the *behaviour*. ie, when you call the `foo()` method, does it do what it's supposed to do?

Unless calling `super.foo()` is part of the *contract* of the sub-class `foo()` method, which is almost a code smell, but there are test frameworks that can specifically assert if certain methods are called. Spock is my favorite (not sure of the syntax, because I've never had to assert calls to super... furher evidence, albeit anecdotal, of code smell. If you method only calls `super.foo()`, delete it and let type hierarchy do it for you.

Comment: Can you please elaborate : `super.foo()` is part of the contract of the sub-class `foo() ` method.

Comment: @FarrukhChishti If the java doc of the method guarantees that `super.foo()` is called. See [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Answer (score 1):

If calling the super method is the only thing this method does, you don't have to create the method in the first place.
Whatever class this is inherits all methods of the super class, meaning you can call `foo()` without overriding it.

If it's not the only thing it does, you can assert the same stuff you assert in the junit test for the super method.